# Messaging Broker for High Latency/Low Connectivity Mesh/Geographically dispersed nodes

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq, messagebroker, nats.io

I am looking for some advice on a clustered or federated broker to use in a given scenario. I will try to describe the problem with what I think is going to be a few critical decision points/information. I believe any solution here will have some custom components and will probably be a mix of technologies, but could be wrong.
Let’s say I have telescopes that are all over the world. They are connected by a mix of satellite links and fiber. I am introducing new telescopes to this mesh all the time as well as sometimes bringing them offline and disconnecting. Because some are connected by satellite links, they have high latency and can go down for extended periods of time.  The idea is to be able to do tasking of these telescopes from any one node (i.e other telescope). So that any node can task any node. If a node is down no tasking is possible (I.e you can’t queue up work for a node that is down). The amount of message traffic between nodes is probably limited to heartbeats, advertising messages at once every few minutes (so advertising capabilities or degraded states), and tasking/status messages that is on demand or sometimes on a multi second interval. We want nodes to be discoverable as they get dynamically added/removed without affecting the configuration of the rest of the mesh (for this reason I can’t just have a configuration file at each node with a list of every node with connections to each).

So I have looked into a few brokers that support clustering to include Kafka, RabbitMQ, and NATS.io. I started down the Kafka path (as that seems popular right now), but I don’t think I require all the stream processing and I hit on a number of sites that said that Kafka requires a reliable network (which makes sense). I have used RabbitMQ in the past for hub and spoke like problems (geographically dispersed) but not unreliable networks were clustered brokers disconnect and reconnect. I have just started researching NATS.io, so I am not as familiar with its capabilities.
So a two things.

**- Am I correct in this case to not go down the Kafka path for this case?**
**- Is there a better clustered broker that may be better suited for this problem space (low connectivity/high latency).**

Again, I believe I want a broker here as I don’t want my Microservices that are running at each node to be worried about reconnection, adding new connections, removing connections, etc.  I want the services abstracted from the overall mesh. I also believe, again, this might be a mix of technologies.  So for instance each node may discover a new node via a clustered broker, but use a more transactional protocol (like HTTPS) to actually task the individual node. This transaction would ensure my task got to the node and insure that it’s a more ACID based transaction (I.e. two nodes trying to task the same node at the same time).
I know this question is a bit open, but looking for some advice from people that have solved a similar problem, and what technologies were helpful.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'd look into MQTT for lightweight protocol to a hub cluster, which you can then optionally forward to kafka, or others, if you did want to actually aggregate data for stream processing needs. Otherwise, Consul or something Raft-based would allow service discovery rather than a message queue